# Is there anyway to prevent 'this' from changing, when I wrap a function?

Tags: javascript, binding

I want all buttons to perform an action before and after their normal onclick event.  So I came up with the "brilliant" idea of looping through all those elements and creating a wrapper function.

This appeared to work pretty well when I tested it, but when I integrated it into our app, it fell apart.  I traced it down to the 'this' value was changed by my wrapper. The sample code illustrates this; before you wrap the event handlers, each button displays the button id when you click, but after wrapping it the displayed name is 'undefined' in this example, or 'Form1' if you run it from within a form.

Does anybody know either a better way to do the same thing?  Or a good way to maintain the originally intended 'this' values?

As you can imagine, I don't want to modify any of the existing event handler code in the target buttons.

Thanks in advance.

PS-The target browser is IE6 & up, crossbrowser functionality not required

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function btnWrap_onClick()
    {
        var btns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
        for( var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++)
        {
            var btn = btns[i];

            // handle wrap button differerntly
            if( "btnWrap" == btn.id)
            {
                btn.disabled = true;
                continue; // skip this button
            }

            // wrap it
            var originalEventHandler = btn.onclick;
            btn.onclick = function()
            {
                alert("Starting event handler");
                originalEventHandler();
                alert("Finished event handler");
            }
        }

        alert("Buttons wrapped successfully");
    }
</script>
<body>
    <p>
    <button id="TestButton1" onclick="alert(this.id);">TestButton1</button>
    <button id="TestButton2" onclick="alert(this.id);">TestButton2</button>
    </p>
    <button id="btnWrap" onclick="btnWrap_onClick();">Wrap Event Handlers</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [Paul Dixon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6521/) said, you could use [call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt1h2e5c.aspx) but I suggest you use [apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zc42wh1(VS.85).aspx) instead.

However, the reason I am answering is that I found a disturbing bug: **You are actually replacing all your event handlers with the event handler of the last button.** I don't think that was what you intended, was it? (Hint: You are replacing the value for originalEventHandler in each iteration)

In the code below you find a working cross-browser solution:

```
function btnWrap_onClick()
{
    var btns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for( var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++)
    {
        var btn = btns[i];

        // handle wrap button differerntly
        if( "btnWrap" == btn.id)
        {
            btn.disabled = true;
            continue; // skip this button
        }

        // wrap it

        var newOnClick = function()
        {
            alert("Starting event handler");
            var src=arguments.callee;
            src.original.apply(src.source,arguments);
            alert("Finished event handler");
        }
        newOnClick.original = btn.onclick; // Save original onClick
        newOnClick.source = btn; // Save source for "this"
        btn.onclick = newOnClick; //Assign new handler
    }
alert("Buttons wrapped successfully");
}
```

First I create a new anonymous function and store that in the variable *newOnClick*. Since a function is an object I can create properties on the function object like any other object. I use this to create the property *original* that is the original onclick-handler, and *source* that is the source element that will be the *this* when the original handler is called.

Inside the anonymous function I need to get a reference to the function to be able to get the value of the properties *original* and *source*. Since the anonymous function don't have a name I use use [arguments.callee](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4esdbwz(VS.85).aspx) (that has been supported since MSIE5.5) to get that reference and store it in variable src.

Then I use the method *apply* to execute the original onclick handler. *apply* takes two parameters: the first is going to be the value of *this*, and the second is an array of arguments. *this* has to be the element where the original onclick handler was attached to, and that value was saved in *source*. *arguments* is an internal property of all functions and hold all the arguments the function was called with (notice that the anonymous function don't have any parameters specified, but if it is called with some parameters anyway, they will be found in the *arguments* property).

The reason I use *apply* is that I can forward all the arguments that the anonymous function was called with, and this makes this function transparent and cross-browser. (Microsoft put the event in window.event but the other browsers supplies it in the first parameter of the handler call)

Comment: Now when I look at this again I realize that it should be refactored to use the same anonymous function, and store the value of the old caller on the original object. That would use less memory.

Comment: Thanks some, I did notice that bug, and was totally perplexed as to how I was going to reference the real original event hanlder, and calling control.  You Rock!

Comment: @John MacIntyre: Thank you John! (I'm just curious if thats your real name or if is a reference to Trapper? Maybe both?) Btw, if you are going to use this in production you should consider to refactor it like I said in my comment above.

Comment: Real name.  I did use it, and it will be rolled into a < 100 user production environment late next week.  But I didn't follow what you were talking about with the refactoring that you mentioned.  Could you append it to your answer?  thx.

Comment: @John: Happy New Year! I'm on vacation for a week and don´t have my tools with me. The solution above works, it is clean, crossbrowser and don't interfere with anything else (it even works if you accidentally call it twice). However, it isn't the most memory efficient since it creates one (cont..)

Comment: anonymous function for every event handler. I would consider to refactor it to use only one function, and that the necessary data was stored at the element object instead.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it, the solution I have in my answer is a generic one that works for every type of event. As long as you keep the code in the function short it is not a big waste of memory.

Comment: Thanks, Some.  Happy New Year to you as well.  I understand what you are saying.  My function is exactly the same as what you have above, with the 2 'alert()'s replaced with my own function calls.  Putting it in the button does make sense, but I'm pretty pleased with what we've got now.

Comment: May I ask you why don't you use your real name?  You're obviously a pretty bright guy, googling you and finding an answer like this would be a pretty good thing I would think.  Or are you some famous programmer who doesn't want to be hassled.  ;-)

Comment: @John: Thank you! Sorry to disappoint you: I'm not a famous programmer. I usually don't use my real name on the net unless it is for official work. Sometimes it is good to be searchable and sometimes it's not and you usually don't know what will bite you until it is too late. I try to prevent (cont)

Comment: bad things from happening by using different names on different sites. It's an old habit and has worked so far. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method to resolve the binding, e.g. `originalEventHandler.call(btn);`

Alternatively, a library like prototype can help - its [bind](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind) method lets you build a new function bound to a specified object, so you'd have declared originalEventHandler as `var originalEventHandler = btn.onclick.bind(btn);`

Finally, for a good backgrounder on binding issues, see also [Getting Out of Binding Situations in JavaScript](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations)

Comment: +1 Thanks alot for the hints Paul.  Just to let you know, I gave the answer to 'some' because he anticipated and answered some barriers I ran into.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the way closures work in JavaScript. Honestly, I'd recommend using a framework. Any of them should make event-handling far nicer than doing it by hand.